# IIS appends /web.config at the end of static files

Tags: iis, static-content, web.config, anonymous

I am trying to debug a 401 error in IIS that happens when serving static files to an anonymous user.

Let's say I'm trying to access `https://example.com/sso.css`. That file physically resides on `D:\website\sso.css`.

Running procmon, I noticed that the w3wp.exe tries to read **`D:\website\sso.css\web.config`** treating the static resource as a folder instead of a file, getting a "File not found" error from the filesystem.

Why is IIS appending `\web.config` when trying to open a file on the physical file system?

Comment: This is a great resource for diagnosing 401 errors - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/907273

Comment: Thanks. Did all of that, and also activated Failed request tracing. Cache seems to be involved. I would like to know why does IIS append this web.config instead of going to the file directly, to work my way up to the root cause from the other end.